# is there a way to know where is the solution from a published site folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a published website that I need to modify, but could not find the solution to open the project. Is there a file, even in the IIS or in the published website folder that could have the path of where that project is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way knowing where your solution is other than searching your hard drives for "*.sln"

Comment: that's what I did and couldn't find anything

Comment: Did you publish the site originally?

Comment: no, it was published by another person and he doesn't work here anymore

Comment: Most likely, its on his PC or Development box/server that he/she used.

Comment: I guess we will have to contact him to see where it is, but thanks anyways for your answer

Comment: Seems like you inherited a mess. Lesson to learn here: use source control like TFS or SVN.